# sinon with promise chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

Im having trouble with sinon when my function returns a chained promise.
Last call is an external http call.

A.ts:

```
export  function someFunctionInClassA(x,y)
{ 
  return B.someFunctionInClassB(x,y).then(
   (resB) =>
         {
           // some code processing resB 
           return someResult
          });
  }
```

B.ts:

```
export function someFunctionInClassB(x,y){
   return some requestPromise.then( // this is the external http
          (resC) =>
              // some code processing resC
             // return resB
    );
 }
```

I want someFunctionInClassA to get a fake resB (so i won't need to do the external call) , and get the someResult for this fake resB. I did:

```
const stubbed = sinon.stub(someBinstance, "someFunctionInClassB");
stubbed.withArgs(x,y).resolves(fakeResB);
someAinstance.init(someBinstance);
stubbed.withArgs(x,y).resolves(fakeResB);
someAinstance.init(someBinstance);

const myWantedRes = someAinstance.someFunctionInClassA(x,y);
```

I tried with ant without wrapping my fakeResB with a promise.
I tried to call .then in myWantedRes.
Help please!

Comment: Would it not make more sense to create stubs for the Ajax library and intercept all HTTP calls?

Comment: @voldemort can you put up the `init` method for `A.ts`?